# adobe air and window.close()

Tags: javascript, air, adobe

I have a simple task to do but I really don't know how to do this. I created a Fullscreen Adobe Air application which does `window.location='http://example.com'` to  load an external page just in a tag.

The problem is that I can't close the Air application from that page using `window.close();` - it just doesn't work. If I load http://example.com into and put a `window.close()` button after tag it works no problem at all. Anyway I can't use as example.com use frames and it stops working properly when loaded to . Could you please help me with that. I hope you understand what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Try using window.nativeWindow.close();

Answer (score 1):

If your using JQuery you can do something like this:

```
 function closeWindow() {
     window.nativeWindow.close();
 }


 $("#buttonClose").click(function() {
     closeWindow();
 });
```

The following functions demonstrate the NativeWindow maximize(), minimize(), restore(), and close() methods, just attach them to HTML elements the same way as above:

```
 function windowMaximize(){ 
     window.nativeWindow.maximize(); 
 } 

 function windowMinimize(){ 
     window.nativeWindow.minimize(); 
 } 

 function windowRestore(){ 
     window.nativeWindow.restore(); 
 } 

 function windowClose(){ 
     window.nativeWindow.close(); 
 }
```

Hope that helps!